# Why did Pundalika order Lord Krishna to stand on the stone?

Tags: krishna, bhakti, vitthal

I have heard the folk story about Pundalika.

He was busy with doing some work and suddenly Lord Krishna came to his home. He ordered Lord Krishna to stand up on the stone. If this is true, then I want to know the full story and any valid reference to it?